# Imagen no carga con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, aplicación-web

¿Por qué mi imagen que tengo en mi escritorio no carga a mi página HTML?
 Lo estoy haciendo a través de JavaScript, pero solo cargan las imágenes de internet poniendo la url.

Éste es mi código:

```
function mostrar()
{
  var src = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\fondo.jpg";
  imagen1.src = src;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué errores ves en la consola de errores de JavaScript? ¿Cómo estás ejecutando tu página web?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes probar añadir file:/// al contenido de la variable `SRC`. Quedaría:

```
var src = "file:///C:Users/User/Desktop/fondo.jpg"
```

Comment: Esto generará un error de seguridad si la página está online, pero funcionará si la página está ejecutándose sin un servidor.